# InfoPath 2013 strange behavior

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have an InfoPath form with 5 page views each dedicated for specific functionality. I also have a workflow that will trigger based on certain fields in the form. When I click on Submit button the form saves the information in a list and a workflow will trigger based on the data submitted.

Recently I have noticed a strange behavior with the form. When I click the button the form waits for a while before it submits the data and I'm not sure why it's happening so.

Can someone please help me with this. I can answer any queries and follow suggestions.